# Duplicate a window in tmux

Tags: tmux

I have a nice window in my `tmux` session that has a number of panes nicely arranged. Is it possible to duplicate a session, preserving the current panes layout?

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the tmux plugins. [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) allows you to save then later restore a set of windows and even the commands running there (out of a limited set you can configure).  You may want to start by first installing the Tmux Plugin Manager that it mentions in the guide if you want to easily try out other plugins.